# css navbar with image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navbar using CSS. The nav links need to be spaced evenly from the picture in the middle of the bar. At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

**The Code:**

```css
body {
  background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
div.menucontainer {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thevincentcollection.com/img/menubg.jpg");
  height: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
  text-align: center;
}
IMG.vcmenulogo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 10px;
}
.menulinks {
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
.menulinks li {
  display:inline;
}
.menulinks a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}
#footer {
  position: fixed; 
  background-image: url("http://www.thevincentcollection.com/img/menubg.jpg");
  box-shadow: 0px -6px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  width:100%;
  height:20;
  bottom:0;
}
P.footer {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Vincent Collection: Luxury in Haircare</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menucontainer">
      <img class="vcmenulogo" src="http://www.thevincentcollection.com/img/vc-logo-menu.png" />
      <ul class="menulinks">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/work/">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"> <p class="footer">Copyright &copy; 2016 Salon on Wheels, LLC. All rights reserved.</p> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the actual question ?

Comment: This maybe can help: http://stanhub.com/how-to-center-a-logo-in-unordered-list-navigation-using-css3-nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your HTML, insert the `img` as `li` and then remove the `position:absolute` from it and with a few other tweaks regarding `position` value and `vertical-align`, you have what you want.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
  margin: 0
}
.menucontainer {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thevincentcollection.com/img/menubg.jpg");
  height: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
  text-align: center;
}
.menulinks {
  position: relative;
  top: -90px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.menulinks li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div class="menucontainer">
  <ul class="menulinks">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/about/">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="vcmenulogo" src="http://www.thevincentcollection.com/img/vc-logo-menu.png" />
    </li>
    <li><a href="/work/">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm new to CSS so when I tried this approach it failed cause I didn't have the right css for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add some space between 2nd and 3rd button as I understood
just give class to 2nd and 3rd li element and give margin. Or maybe you can just add 2 ul elements and margin between

Answer (score 0):

@joshua, its a gud approach to do as @ryuk said as well, and if i was to do this i would just make a dummy `li` between 2nd and 3rd child then margin it appropriately.
U can either do this,

`<ul class="menulinks">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
        <li class="third"><a href="/work/">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>`

```
.third{ margin-left: 10% }
```

or make a dummy between 2nd and 3rd `li`

```
     <ul class="menulinks">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
        <li class="dummy"></li>
        <li><a href="/work/">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

.dummy{
    padding-left:10%
}
```